# Compatibility issue between otftotfm and Adobe Acrobat Reader

Tags: adobe, otftotfm, simpleicons

My MWE was the next:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{simpleicons}% some version prior to 9.something,
                        % current version 9.10.1 does not have the issue
\begin{document}
Windows: \simpleicon{windows}
Adobe Acrobat Reader: \simpleicon{adobeacrobatreader}
\end{document}
```

I compiled it with pdflatex.
When viewing the result in Adobe Acrobat Reader (on Windows), the icons were not visible.

[image: output as shown by Adobe Acrobat Reader on Windows]

At the same time, there never was such problem in other pdf viewers (e.g. SumatraPDF).

[image: output as shown by SumatraPDF]

The [SimpleIcons package](https://ctan.org/pkg/simpleicons) has a SimpleIcons.otf font file. When creating the package, this file was converted with `otftotfm` to SimpleIcons.pfb font file. The pfb file is used only when **`pdflatex`** is used for compilation (not LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX).

When SimpleIcons.otf is converted with Fontforge to SimpleIcons.pfb, the icons are visible also when using Adobe Acrobat Reader (on Windows). (This is the current approach by the SimpleIcons-package.) Therefore there was some issue with the conversion from SimpleIcons.otf to SimpleIcons.pfb by `otftotfm`.

The author of the SimpleIcons package tells us (at https://github.com/ineshbose/simple-icons-latex/issues/11#issuecomment-1657120754):

> Regarding how otftotfm is being setup and used, the pipeline installs
> the default/latest version
>
> simple-icons-latex/.github/workflows/release.yml
>
> Lines 48 to 49 in 65cd52d

```
    - name: Install otftotfm 
      run: sudo apt-get install -y lcdf-typetools
```

> and then is run like so:
>
> simple-icons-latex/bindings.js
>
> Lines 102 to 109 in 65cd52d

```
return execSync(
  [
   `otftotfm ${"SimpleIcons.otf"}`,
   `--literal-encoding=${file}`,
   `--name=SimpleIcons--${filename}`,
  ].join(" "),
  { encoding: "utf-8" }
).replace(/SimpleIconsFiltered/g, "SimpleIcons");
```

Was something wrong with the calling of `otftotfm`, or is something wrong "inside" `otftotfm`? See also https://github.com/kohler/lcdf-typetools/issues/34.

Comment: with texlive 2023 I get `LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape \`U/simpleiconsOneZero/m/n' undefined (Font)              using \`U/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 4.` and letters not icons, it appears the package is not set up in texlive?

Comment: works (including in acrobat) with lualatex

Comment: ah the fd files in the package have the wrong name

Comment: once fd files fixed I see same issue in acrobat

Comment: @David Carlisle It really works with lualatex in acrobat. On the other hand, I get an error with xelatex.

Comment: `Missing character: There is no   (U+0020) in font SimpleIcons Filtered!` that?

Comment: @David Carlisle I have this error with xelatex: `! Font TU/SimpleIcons(0)/m/n/10=SimpleIcons at 10.0pt not loadable: Metric (TFM
) file or installed font not found.` I use an up-to-date TeX Live 2023 on Windows 10.

Comment: oh it didn't find the otf fle have you set up fontconfig  to search texlive? what happens if you change `\newfontfamily{\simpleiconsmap}{SimpleIcons}` to `\newfontfamily{\simpleiconsmap}{SimpleIcons.otf}`  in the package

Comment: @David Carlisle Yes, that solves the problem with xelatex, and in this case the result will be fine in acrobat. The pdflatex remains problematic.

Comment: well adobe really doesn't like the type1 font (the pfb), the otf version looks ok, but there is no error. It looks like a scaling problem. If I enlarge the font a lot a small blob appears on the page. No idea what happens here but the FontMatrix value looks unusual in the font.

Comment: If I use `{\fontsize{10cm}{10cm}\selectfont \simpleicon{windows}}` in your example and then zoom in at 2400% I get this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/T7Hh8.png

Comment: If I change in an hex editor in the pdf the fontmatrix from `/FontMatrix [0.000833333333333 0 0 0.000833333333333 0 0]` to the standard `/FontMatrix [0.001             0 0 0.001             0 0]`  (the spaces are needed to keep the file length constant) the icons reappear.

Comment: @David Carlisle I tried it, it works for me too.

Comment: I'm not David Carlisle ...

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer I'm sorry, I was careless!

Comment: @Stephen, OK, thank you!