# Conversion from SimpleIcons.otf to SimpleIcons.pfb by otftotfm

Tags: otftotfm, simpleicons

The [SimpleIcons package](https://ctan.org/pkg/simpleicons) has a SimpleIcons.otf font file. When creating the package, this file is converted with `otftotfm` to SimpleIcons.pfb font file. The pfb file is used only when **`pdflatex`** is used for compilation (not LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX). Unfortunately, when viewing the resulting pdf in **Adobe Acrobat Reader (on Windows)**, the icons are not visible (but is visible in a lot of other viewers). When SimpleIcons.otf is converted via https://convertio.co to SimpleIcons.pfb, the icons are visible. Therefore there is some issue with the conversion from SimpleIcons.otf to SimpleIcons.pfb by `otftotfm`.

The author of the SimpleIcons package tells us (at https://github.com/ineshbose/simple-icons-latex/issues/11#issuecomment-1657120754):

> Regarding how otftotfm is being setup and used, the pipeline installs
> the default/latest version
>
> simple-icons-latex/.github/workflows/release.yml
>
> Lines 48 to 49 in 65cd52d

```
    - name: Install otftotfm 
      run: sudo apt-get install -y lcdf-typetools
```

> and then is run like so:
>
> simple-icons-latex/bindings.js
>
> Lines 102 to 109 in 65cd52d

```
return execSync(
  [
   `otftotfm ${"SimpleIcons.otf"}`,
   `--literal-encoding=${file}`,
   `--name=SimpleIcons--${filename}`,
  ].join(" "),
  { encoding: "utf-8" }
).replace(/SimpleIconsFiltered/g, "SimpleIcons");
```

What needs to be changed to get a working SimpleIcons.pfb file?

Comment: Would it be better to edit the additional information in this question into the existing one? That one looks to have some potentially useful comments? @DavidCarlisle

Comment: @cfr yes, probably

Comment: Copied the information from here to https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/689446/6865 but cannot close my own question as duplicate, because there is no upvoted answer at that question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/689446/why-is-adobe-acrobat-reader-not-compatible-with-the-simpleicons-package and it makes sense to combine the questions, even though neither currently has an answer. The OP has already added information from this question into the earlier one, but this one can't be closed as an official SE duplicate due to the lack of an upvoted answer.